What could cause IP packets to be sent using an interface with the source address of a different interface?
An embedded Linux system is being used to monitor a network on interface lan2, and save results locally, to be downloaded later over interface wwan0.
wwan0 is a cellular modem on a private APN.
  inet 10.250.32.22/30 brd 10.250.32.23 scope global wwan0

lan2 is an ethernet port that obtains an ipv4 address by DHCP from an ISP.
 inet 98.95.117.12/22  brd 98.95.119.255 scope global lan2

The cellular carrier for wwan0 is regularly disconnecting wwan0 because of "IP Source Address Violations". IP packets with a source address of 98.95.117.12 are being sent over wwan0.  There are no routes between lan2 and wwan0.
I understand that a packet could be routed out the wwan0 interface toward it's gateway depending on the metrics, but if the wwan0 interface is used, then the source address should be that of the wwan0 interface.
What circumstances could cause a packet to be sent from the wwan0 interface using source address of the lan2 interface?

This isn't routing. See the following. On Linux, bind() can typically ensure the source of the packet, even if it conflicts with the routing table. https://stackoverflow.com/a/173193/175990

This is also influenced by platform. For example, Linux has a different "host model" than Windows. This influences how interfaces can be selected for sending.

@GregAskew,  would using a command like ping -W 1 -I lan2 -c 1 $host  cause a packet to be sent out wwan0 with the source address of lan2 if the lan2 interface was down?  How can I avoid sending packets out wwan0 with the source address of lan2?

@GregAskew, the question you linked is using C code - I am working only with bash shell scripts, so I don't think bind() is applicable, unless it is through an incorrect understanding of how the -I option of ping works...

Read LARTC, it answers your problem exactly.


but if the wwan0 interface is used, then the source address should be that of the wwan0 interface.

That is only guaranteed when you have iptables SNAT/MASQUERADE rules explicitly overwriting the source address.
In basic IP operation, though, the system doesn't enforce this in any way – a route may only hint at a preferred source address if the application doesn't bind to one, but otherwise the two are independent. So even if an application binds to the local address of interface A, the packets will still follow the preferred default route even if it leads through interface B.
Basically the Linux network stack doesn't have any understanding of multi-homed hosts that have two independent ISP connections, and assumes that all interfaces are connected to [different subnets of] the same broader network where asymmetric routing is allowed (like if it were connected to an internal enterprise network, or maybe 1970s ARPANET). It requires manual configuration (e.g. policy routing) to achieve any form of multi-homing support.

(As a general example where it would be valid behavior, though, a host with two interfaces might not have default routes through both interfaces. If it is contacted by its interface A's address, but the only route for sending a reply is through interface B, it cannot just invent a route through interface A instead: it has to reply through interface B.
For a slightly different example where replying through the "wrong" interface is normal, a router connected to multiple subnets of the same network might have an OSPF-routed "loopback" address that is assigned to 'lo', and it would be completely normal for it to originate packets from its 'loopback' address and send them through eth0 or eth2.)


That being said, the Linux IPv6 stack follows a slightly stricter host model, and has an optional "use_oif_addrs_only" sysctl to restrict the automatic selection of source IP address to only those assigned to the outgoing interface. But its IPv4 stack has no such thing (as far as I know; no, not the arp_* knobs) and assumes that all addresses simply belong to the host as a whole. (And in a similar vein, the IPv6 stack supports simple routing based on both source & destination, while for IPv4 that requires a more complex "policy routing" setup.)
Suggestions to try:

When adding default routes, define the "preferred source" hint for each (in ip route that's the src parameter, in netlink it's RTA_PREFSRC).

Add the default routes to two separate routing tables, and use policy routing via ip rule to enforce that e.g. packets with source 98.95.117.12 will use a routing table that only has routes through lan2.
ip route add default via ... table 123
ip route add default via ... table 456
ip rule add from ... lookup 123
ip rule add from ... lookup 456


As last resort, set up iptables/nftables masquerade rules for both interfaces, like if this were a router.
oifname "wwan0" masquerade



